# ASP.NET 5 and Yeoman genetaror issue

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, npm-install

First of all I looked into `[this][1]` post for possible workaround but unfortunately there is none.

My issue is somewhat closer but steps I went through are different so I decided to put up my question in a new thread.

### My requirements were:

1. Installing ASP.NET 5 but I did not want to install full `VS 2015` rather I went for `DNVM` (`Dot Net Version Manager`) and `DNX (NET Execution Environment)`. [This post](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html#id2) says we can install from Command Line tool so I used this.
2. Installing `Code for Visual Studio` which I did
3. Installing a `aspnet-generator` using `yo` which I did using the following command: `npm install -g yo generator-aspnet` but ended up with some error messages. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

4. Even I got above errors I went on and ran `yo aspnet` which was supposed to give me choice of what type of application I want to create etc. But here I ended up with errors again. Please see screenshot below:

[image]

I googled a lot but nothing looked suitable or closer to my issue. I don't want to play with Windows Registry.

I am completely screwed up with this problem :( Somebody please show me the right path and help me out of this stand-still situation.

Thank you

Comment: The errors in step 3 are npm issues and don't have anything to do with asp.net 5 specifically. Since you didn't successfully install the generator, the error in step 4 is related to the fact that the generator isn't installed correctly.  I'd try to diagnose your node/npm install.  Do you have issues installing other node modules globally?

Comment: As far as I can remember I did not have to install any node module manually so far. They all got installed with Polymer Start Kit. And I did not have any issue installed bower_components using bower so far. May be this is a separate thing from node module installation, but mentioned if they are related somewhere.

Comment: You can go to an empty directory and try to install locally (i.e. no -g flag) yo and aspnet-generator and see if that works.  Doesn't address the underlying issue with your node installation, but it may get this specific issue addressed.

Comment: It gets installed locally! However I got this message at the end "npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Projects\empty\package.json'" but the Errors have disappeared and I can see a node_module is added under D:\Projects\empty folder. And also yo aspnet is running now with the options to select. What should now be my action? Should I continue with local installation?

Comment: I haven't seen any warnings or errors on the machines I've used to play with DNX, so your results may be iffy.  You may want to try cleaning off all things node related and reinstall node from scratch to try and eliminate errors before continuing, but if you have enough to bring up the test project and access it, it may be enough for you.

Comment: Yes, for now my main objective is to see how this works. I am going through a learning process at the moment. So if local installation and test project works for me that would be great. You have mode my day. Thank you so much Steve for taking time and bring me to some platform where I can at least start!

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a bug with npm. Here is the usual troubleshoot:

1. Make sure you're on the latest npm version
2. Delete the node_modules folders and retry installation

If this doesn't fix it, then you should open an issue on the npm bug tracker.

Comment: I did a fresh node.js installation (4.2.3 LTS) from https://nodejs.org/en/. Created an empty folder and ran `npm install -g gulp bower`. Still getting a lot of errors. I opened an issue @ https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10761